# Are there Python packages for recent Bayesian optimization methods?

Tags: python, hyperparameter-optimization, resource-request, bayesian-optimization

I want to try and compare different optimization methods in some datasets. I know that in scikit-learn there are some corresponding functions for the grid and random search optimizations. However, I also need a package (or multiple ones) for different recent Bayesian optimization methods.

Are there any good and stable ones to use? Which packages do you recommend? (If any recent for grid/random search, it is also okay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the [Scikit-Optimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/) package related to [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/), following are some of the packages related to Bayesian optimization:

1. [GPyOpt](https://sheffieldml.github.io/GPyOpt/)
2. [pyGPGO](https://pygpgo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
3. [Hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt)
4. [bayesian-optimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization)
5. [safeopt](https://github.com/befelix/SafeOpt)
6. [RoBO](https://github.com/automl/RoBO)